# How to compare String and string in enum

Tags: java, html, spring, model-view-controller, playback

I'm new in MVC programming.
So I'm using play framework.

Here is the enum from my model:

```
public enum Status{
    CREATED, 
    MODERATED, 
    REJECTED, 
    REPLIED, 
    REPLY 
}

@Column(name="status_")
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
public Status status;

public String getStatus() {
    return status;
}
```

Now, I need to access the $status from the view (html) and compare the string:

```
#{if programComment.getStatus()=="MODERATED"}
<div>
 ...
</div>
#{/if}
```

but it gives me error:

> Getting Uncaught ReferenceError: MODERATED is not defined

Comment: Hi, does your code compile? You have `public Status status;` and `public String getStatus()`

Answer (score 1):

after long play with quotes, I found the answer:

```
#{if "${programComment.getStatus()}"=="MODERATED"}
<div>
...
</div>
#{/if}
```

So, I wrapped the variable with double quotations.